# Trouble using MPI_BCAST with MPI_CART_CREATE

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am having trouble with MPI_BCAST in Fortran. I create a new communicator using MPI_CART_CREATE (say 'COMM_NEW'). When I broadcast data from root using old communicator (i.e. MPI_COMM_WORLD) it works fine. But, when i use new communicator that i just created it gives the error:

```
[compute-4-15.local:15298] *** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast
[compute-4-15.local:15298] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[compute-4-15.local:15298] *** MPI_ERR_COMM: invalid communicator
[compute-4-15.local:15298] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
```

It do get the result from the processors involved in COMM_NEW, and also the above error,  think the problem is with other processors which are not included in COMM_NEW, but are present in MPI_COMM_WORLD. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Is it because the number of processors in COMM_NEW is less than total processors. If so how do i broadcast among a set of processors which are less than the total. Thanks. 
My sample code is:

```
!PROGRAM TO BROADCAST THE DATA FROM ROOT TO DEST PROCESSORS
PROGRAM MAIN
IMPLICIT NONE
INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
!____________________________________________________________________________________
!-------------------------------DECLARE VARIABLES------------------------------------
INTEGER :: ERROR, RANK, NPROCS, I
INTEGER :: SOURCE, TAG, COUNT, NDIMS, COMM_NEW
INTEGER :: A(10), DIMS(1)
LOGICAL :: PERIODS(1), REORDER
!____________________________________________________________________________________
!-------------------------------DEFINE VARIABLES-------------------------------------
SOURCE = 0; TAG = 1; COUNT = 10
PERIODS(1) = .FALSE.
REORDER = .FALSE.
NDIMS = 1
DIMS(1) = 6
!____________________________________________________________________________________
!--------------------INITIALIZE MPI, DETERMINE SIZE AND RANK-------------------------
CALL MPI_INIT(ERROR)
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, NPROCS, ERROR)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, RANK, ERROR)
!
CALL MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, NDIMS, DIMS, PERIODS, REORDER, COMM_NEW, ERROR)

IF(RANK==SOURCE)THEN
DO I=1,10
  A(I) = I
END DO
END IF
!____________________________________________________________________________________
!----------------BROADCAST VECTOR A FROM ROOT TO DESTINATIONS------------------------

CALL MPI_BCAST(A,10,MPI_INTEGER,SOURCE,COMM_NEW,ERROR)

!PRINT*, RANK
!WRITE(*, "(10I5)") A

CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ERROR)

END PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error you give at the top of your question doesn't match up with the code at the bottom since it's complaining about a Bcast on MPI_COMM_WORLD and you don't actually do one in your code.

Anyway, if you're running with more processes than dimensions, some of the processes won't be included in COMM_NEW. Instead, when the call to MPI_CART_CREATE returns, they'll get MPI_COMM_NULL for COMM_NEW instead of the new communicator with the topology. You just need to do a check to make sure you have a real communicator instead of MPI_COMM_NULL before doing the Bcast (or just have all of the ranks above DIMS(1) not enter the Bcast.

Comment: +1. Open MPI uses `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in all error messages related to an invalid communicator handle being supplied - see my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. I had been able to find the error and its as you guys pointed out. It works when i call MPI_BCAST just within COMM_NEW using an if condition.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Wesley Bland's answer and to clarify the apparent discrepancy in the error message. When the number of MPI processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is larger than the number of processes in the created Cartesian grid, some of the processes won't become members of the new Cartesian communicator and will get `MPI_COMM_NULL` -- the invalid communicator handle -- as a result. Calling a collective communication operation requires a valid inter- or intra-communicator handle. Unlike the allowed usage of `MPI_PROC_NULL` in point-to-point operations, using the invalid communicator handle in collective calls is erroneous. The last statement is not explicitly written in the MPI standard - instead, the language used is:

> If `comm` is an intracommunicator, then ... If `comm` is an intercommunicator, then ...

Since `MPI_COMM_NULL` is neither an intra-, nor an inter-communicator, it doesn't fall in any of the two categories of defined behaviour and hence leads to an error condition.

Since communication errors have to occur in some context (i.e. in a valid communicator), Open MPI substitutes `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in the call to the error handler and hence the error message says "`*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD`". This is the relevant code section from `ompi/mpi/c/bcast.c`, where `MPI_Bcast` is implemented:

```c
if (ompi_comm_invalid(comm)) {
    return OMPI_ERRHANDLER_INVOKE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_ERR_COMM, 
                               FUNC_NAME);
}
...
if (MPI_IN_PLACE == buffer) {
    return OMPI_ERRHANDLER_INVOKE(comm, MPI_ERR_ARG, FUNC_NAME);
}
```

Your code triggers the error handler inside the first check. In all other error checks `comm` is used instead (since it is determined to be a valid communicator handle) and the error message will state something like "`*** on communicator MPI COMMUNICATOR 5 SPLIT FROM 0`".